# How can I make Windows Live Messenger 2011 less laggy?

Tags: performance, windows-live-messenger

I am using MSN 2011 and think they did a terrible job on it. It seems quite buggy. At times, when I type a message, it is like a slide show. If I would type a sentence, it would really struggle, and the sentence would show up only seconds after I typed it.

This only happens sometimes. I heard this has something to do with some advertisements making it slow.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Also, I noticed that like 70% of the time, when I check auto login (remember my password and username) it forgets that I checked the box the next time I start my computer up, so I end up typing in my username and password again.

Comment: Is this on Vista or Windows 7? How much RAM do you have? What speed connection do you have?

Comment: @Randolph Potter - Windows 7 enterprise 64bit edition, 8 gigs of ram, dsl connection.

Comment: Another question: do you use your ISP's DNS settings, or a third party like Google's? This might be a direction to look into.

Comment: @Randolph Potter  - What do you mean ISP' DNS settings or third party like Google?

Comment: Well I thought the question was quite clear. Do you use the DNS server settings as provided by your ISP, or did you change them to those of another provider, like Google or OpenDNS?

Comment: @Randolph Potter  - No it is not quite clear as when you said DSN settings I was thinking of something completely different ie options that you set. I did not think that you meant am I using another DSN server provider. So no I use the default dsn provider of my isp.

Comment: I said DNS. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try changing your DNS settings on your router to Google public DNS* or OpenDNS.

Google public DNS servers are as follows:

```
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4
```

*(Instructions for Google from [here](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using.html).)*

For OpenDNS, use the following DNS servers instead:

```
208.67.222.222
208.67.220.220
```

---

**DNS stands for Domain Name Service.*